# PHP : Check if string contains specific mention?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
$a = 'How are you? @android_ar';

if ($a contains '@android_ar')
    echo 'true';
```

Suppose I have the code above, what is the correct way to write the statement if `($a contains '@android_ar')`?

Note:

The mention (`@android_ar`) its change every time. So we can change it every time and not fixed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos($a, '@android_ar') !== false`.

Answer (score 1):

as with all php code there are lots of ways to do this and everyone has their own idea, but check out [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

e.g.

```
$test = '@android_ar';
if (strtr($a,$test))
    echo 'true';
```

see also:
[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string
[stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) - Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string
[strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) - Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string
[strripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) - Find the position of the last occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string
[strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) - Find the first occurrence of a string
[strpbrk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) - Search a string for any of a set of characters
[substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - Return part of a string
[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - Perform a regular expression match